# c# Delegate Throws System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Thread that retrieves infos from an xml file. In my main form I have a checkbox that in case a boolean in the xml is true must be checked by the thread. I have created a Delegate but despite this when the thread tries to change the value of the checkbox a System.InvalidOperationException is thrown. Why ?!?

```
private delegate void ProjectFileReloadDelegate(string pp);

private void ProjectFileReload(string projectPath)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new ProjectFileReloadDelegate(ProjectFileReload), projectPath);
    }
    else
    {
        //This throws the exception
        //I retrive the anchorMode Info 
        anchorMode.Checked = ProjectOptions_v000.AnchorMode;
    }
```

Comment: Check if `anchorMode` needs invokation, rather than `this`

Comment: what is `this` or more specific where does `Invoke` come from? Furthermore what is `anchorMode`?

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF? Anyway, you can't change a UI component from a thread other than the UI thread. If you want to change it you need to dispatch the GUI change back to the UI thread, e.g. in WinForms by calling the components Invoke method.

Comment: Using InvokeRequired like this is a strong anti-pattern.  It is very difficult to be sure that code is thread-safe when you have no idea on what thread such code runs.  In practice you always know.  As-is, you are subject to a threading race bug, bummer if InvokeRequired is false but turns true just before you set the Checked property.  Low odds, not zero, you might have started the thread too early.  If the exception is consistent then consider that it is raised by ProjectOptions_v000.  Should be a POCO and not a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one of my projects, which handled quite a few API, I used Task to handle async api calls. Due to the uncertainty on weather it would be on Main GUI thread or another I used Task.Factory.StartNew with a TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() as parameter to handle any code updating the GUI. The reference for this is from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8#Default) the section titled "Specifying a synchronization context"
The TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() tells it run on gui thread.

This is how I would update your code to prevent Exceptions from updating GUI content on other threads.

```
    private delegate void ProjectFileReloadDelegate(string pp);

    private void ProjectFileReload(string projectPath)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new ProjectFileReloadDelegate(ProjectFileReload), projectPath);
        }
        else
        {
            //This throws the exception
            //I retrive the anchorMode Info 

            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                       delegate {
                           anchorMode.Checked = ProjectOptions_v000.AnchorMode;
                       }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
                   );
```

Comment: If my answer worked for you could you mark it as the answer?